# How do i remove empty excel sheet while exporting the report in SSRS 2008R2?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

I have one issue with SSRS reports.
i ll export the report with excel format. but unfartunatily excel page break empty sheet will created. how do i remove that empty excel sheet from SSRS 2008R2.EX: sheet1 contain data and sheet2 not contain data and sheet3 contain data. How do i remove the sheet2?
Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score -1):

You may create new file and to change all info to it

Comment: when i export the report from SSRS they will create blank page sheet. i have 2 tabs in that report tab1 containing data and tab2 created default by page break and tab3 containing data. now i need to remove tab2 blank page sheet. How to achieve this?